# Access testData from beforeEach for parameterized test

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, parameterized-unit-test

I do want to create test data in the `beforeEach` method and access that data to give to the parameterized test but I get an error `TS2454: Variable  testData  is used before being assigned.`

```
describe('Test', async () => {
  let testProduct: Product

  beforeEach(async () => {
      testData = await createUser();
  })

  [
    { input: testProduct.id, error: false }, // TS2454: Variable  testData  is used before being assigned
    { input: "Non Existent", error: true },
  ].forEach(({ input, error }) => 
    it('Test Query', async () => {
      const client = createApolloTestClient();
      const res = await client.query<{userFound: boolean}, {id: string}>({
        query: ProductQuery,
        variables: {id: input}
      });
      expect(res.data?.userFound).toBe(error)
    }))
})
```

How can I refactor this to make it work?

Comment: You're missing many closing parentheses...

Comment: (Also FWIW I think having conditional behaviour inside the test suggests that those two cases _shouldn't_ be parameterised. Just write two tests.)

Comment: There was one parenthesis too many. I deleted it.
Also yes the expected is simplified cause I didn't want to copy & paste my production code. I still need it as parameterized

Comment: No, you have quite a lot too few. What you've posted isn't JavaScript.

Comment: True it's Typescript. Where do you want to see extra paranthesis?
Just for you I removed the condition

Comment: It's really not, for the same syntactic reasons, and it's not a matter of my preference. Get you an editor/IDE that highlights unclosed parens (even [the playground](https://tsplay.dev/w8QlpN) does it). And note that even once you've fixed that, you need to think about test _discovery_ time (when the `forEach` runs) vs. _execution_ time (when `beforeEach` runs).